# package org.apache.commons.lang3.time does not exist in idea java Scratch file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I create a new Java scratch file in Intellij with this code:

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateFormatUtils;

class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(DateFormatUtils.format(new Date(), "yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
    }
}
```

It shows

> "Error:(2, 37) package org.apache.commons.lang3.time does not exist".

I only can use the jdk lib.
How can I modify the classpath used to run Intellij scratch files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to specify the module with the dependencies in run configuration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewS0T.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTimeFormatter to formate a given date to string, as follow:

```
    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    String text = date.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: It's just an example. I want to use the third-party lib in the scratch.